# Android tablet/device with 2 wifi adapters

Tags: wi-fi

Is there a way to add a 2nd WiFi adapter to an Android device?

I'm looking to use an Android based device as a proxy for an upcoming pentesting project. I know I can use a laptop or another device like a Pineapple, but this is a bit of a special needs project for reasons I can't elaborate more upon.

I'm looking for 2 wireless adapters so I can connect wirelessly to the internet and use the 2nd adapter as a access point that other devices can connect to.

Any thoughts/ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: We need you to be a bit more elaborate. Why are you seeking an Android device that has multiple wireless NICs? What do you intend to use it for? Have you done your own search already? What did it turn up? You need to help us help you.

Comment: Product/shopping recommendations are off-topic for SU (and other SE sites) - so I edited that part out.  What makes you think you CAN'T [add a WiFi dongle via USB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1484339)?  What did you try?  What were the results?

Comment: Thanks for info techie007. Most android tablets I've seen haven't had USB ports but I will look into that option and add a 2nd adapter if possible.

Comment: Here's something I just ran across that you may find useful in this project (even if not directly answering the problem at hand): [How to tell if your Android phone or tablet supports USB On-The-Go](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-tell-if-your-android-phone-or-tablet-supports-usb-on-the-go/) - Leads to [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.shajul.usbotg).

Comment: Excellent - Thank you techie007, that is exactly what I needed!